# three js glb export wireframe is only noise

Tags: html, three.js, blender, babylonjs

im exporting my rhino to 3ds and from 3ds with blender to glb and removeing everything to lower size but my wirefram look like this

[image]

but same gltb in babylon is look like this :

[image]

what im missing here ? this is my loader code

```
                THREE.DRACOLoader.setDecoderPath( 'files/draco/' );
            var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
            loader.setDRACOLoader( new THREE.DRACOLoader() );
            loader.load( 'files/valiDraco1.glb', function ( gltf ) {

                gltf.scene.traverse( function ( child ) {

                    if ( child.isMesh ) {

                        //child.material.envMap = envMap;
                        child.material.wireframe = true;

                    }

                } );
                childs = gltf.scene;
                scene.add( gltf.scene );

            } );
```

Comment: Can you please share the `glb` file in this thread?

Comment: Perhaps try replacing each material with `child.material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xffffff })`.

Answer (score 0):

THREE Wireframe defaults to textured if you have a texture in your material. If you assign an untextured material as Don McCurdy suggested.. they should look pretty similar.